# pandas df column to date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas df column that has a 10 digit timestamp? it is a type('O') and I am trying to get it into datetime format of mm-dd-yyyy

```
date
1534636800
1534723200
1534809600
1534896000
```

i tried

`all_data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

which returned

```
datetime
1970-01-01 00:00:01.534636800
1970-01-01 00:00:01.534723200
1970-01-01 00:00:01.534809600
1970-01-01 00:00:01.534896000
```

This is obviously incorrect.

I also tried
`all_data['datetime'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(all_data['date'].astype(int))`
and
`all_data['datetime'] = pd.datetime(all_data['date'].astype(int))`

Both return errors "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"

Comment: just pass `unit` parameter in `to_datetime()` method...i.e `all_data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['date'],unit='s')`

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':[
1534636800,
1534723200,
1534809600,
1534896000,]
})
df
```

**Code**

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='s')
df
```

**Output**

```
    date
0   2018-08-19
1   2018-08-20
2   2018-08-21
3   2018-08-22
```